# Build Flow job working issue with Multijob project

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-build-flow

I have added the build flow job with my multijob.
I faced some issues with build flow job. It always executes twice whenever I gave build.

Is there anybody faced and solved this issue previously?

Comment: Did you [✔] _Enable retry_ in the corresponding MultiJob Phase?

Comment: why should I enable retry button?

Comment: You should NOT. But if you, or someone else, enabled it erroneously this could be a reason for executing more than once.